# How to set a YouTube playlist as an "official series playlist" using the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I would like to be able to set a YouTube playlist as an "official series playlist" using the YouTube API, but I can't seem to find the configuration property in the YouTube documentation. Is this even possible?

This is the setting I'd like to control via API:

[image]

I am currently looking at the documentation on this page, but I can't find anything related to series playlisting! What am I missing?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists#resource

Thanks!